# PHP : How to count array if value > 10 without looping?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there anyway to count array if value > 10 without looping(foreach)?

```
$arr=array(5,7,11,67,4,12,15);
$wanted_output=4
```

Comment: What do you mean by `count array values more than 10 ` can you give examples

Comment: If you want to count the numer of elements use count($array);

Comment: @Baba I think he need to count the number of values

Comment: @Gautam3164 what if he just wanted to count the arrays ??? Question is too ambiguous

Comment: Use count() with array_filter() and a callback that returns TRUE if value > 10.... it's still a loop, but an internal loop

Comment: I don't know why somebody do down vote. Please comment reason for downvote

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `array_reduce` then you don't need `count`

```
echo array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($b > 10) ? ++$a : $a;
}); // returns 4
```

Comment: I have a doubt. What does the first and second parameter $a and $b signify ? What if i do $a > 10 and $b ++ ?

Comment: `$a` is used as the counter, `$b` is the individual array values

Comment: @Mark I understood that but why only $a is used as a counter. What if i do $a > 10 and $b ++ ?

Comment: It's the use of `and` rather than `&&` to handle operator precedence that's clever

Comment: `$a` is good and `$b` is bad ... the come together to from `ying yang` here is a test http://eval.in/31450

Comment: @Vivek - if you do them the wrong way round, you'll get a wrong result... $a starts at zero, so never gets incremented, so you'll always get a 0

Comment: My question is why the second parameter of a user defined function is mapping the values of the array ?

Comment: @Vivek - because the developers of PHP chose to write it that way

Answer (score 2):

```
$minVal = 10;
$counter = count(
    array_filter(
        $myArray,
        function($value) use ($minVal) {
            return $value > $minVal;
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

From PHP7.4, you can use `array_reduce()` with arrow function syntax and avoid the `use()` syntax to make the minimum threshold available inside the function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nC28D))

```
$array = [5, 7, 11, 67, 4, 12, 15];
$min = 10;
echo array_reduce($array, fn($carry, $item) => $carry + ($item > $min), 0);
// output: 4
```

The true|false evaluation between `$item` and `$min` equates to 1|0 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **array_count_values** like

```
print_r(array_count_values($my_array));
```

If he need to count the values less than 10 try like

```
$my_array = array_filter($my_array, function ($n) {
    return $n > 10;
});
echo count($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_count_values:-

```
$array = array(1, 38, 1, 38,35);
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Output:-

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [38] => 2
    [35] => 1
)
```

Using array_filter:-

```
$arraycount = array_filter($array, function ($n) {
    return $n > 10;
});
echo count($arraycount);
```